# performance improvement of queries against encrypted table without changing the application code

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, database-performance

I have tagged this problem with both Oracle and Java because both Oracle and Java solutions would be accepted for this problem.

I am new to Oracle security and have been presented with the below problem to solve. I have done some research on the internet but I have had no luck so far. At first, I thought `Oracle TDE` might be helpful for my problem but here: [Can Oracle TDE protect data from the DBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591112/can-oracle-tde-protect-data-from-the-dba) it seems `TDE` doesn't protect data against `DBA` and this is an issue which is not to be tolerated.

Here is the problem:

I have a table containing millions of records. I have a Java application which queries this table using equality or range criteria against a column in the table which is the primary key column of the table. The primary key column contains sensitive data and thus has been encrypted already. As the result, querying data using normal (i.e. decrypted) values from the application cannot use the primary key's unique index access path. I need to improve the queries' performance without any changes on the application code (application config can be modified if necessary but not the code). It would be OK to do any changes that are necessary on the database side as long as that column remains encrypted.

**Oracle people please:** What solution(s) do you suggest to this problem? How can I create an index on decrypted column values and somehow force Oracle to utilize this index? How can I use partitioning such as hash-partitioning? How about views? Any, Any solution?

**Java people please:** I myself have this very vague idea which is to create a separate application in between (i.e between the database and the application) which acts as a proxy that receives the queries from the application and replaces the decrypted values with encrypted values and sends it for the database, it then receives the response and return the results back to the application. The proxy should behave like a database so that it should be possible for the application to connect to it by changing the connection string in the configuration file only. Would this work? How?

Thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're a victim of very poor database design practices. The primary key should be meaningless, and the facts that it is encrypted for protection and subject to range scans indicates that it is not in this case.

I know that's not directly helpful, but if the solution that you come up with has poor performance or is a dreadful hack then at least you can point to this issue in defence -- there is rarely an elegant solution to a problem of poor basic design practices.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the sort of query that you run against the table at the moment? Can you confirm that the query does something along the lines of "decrypt_function(encrypted_primary_key_column) = 'unencrypted_value_from_java"?

Comment: I was going to write some suggestions before I realized that there is a no way to do range searches without compromising the private key to dba (unless using order preserving encryption algorithm)

Comment: @David Aldridge That a primary key should be meaningless is a topic for debate. Natural vs. surrogate primary keys. But I agree that encrypting a natural primary key is not a good choice. A lesson to be learned for me : if you use natural primary keys never use data in it that might be considered sensitive now or in the future.

Comment: Any "order preserving algorithm" is very easy to crack with a brute force search (since really you only need a binary search to decode a value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which queries this table using equality or range criteria against a column in the table which is the primary key column of the table

To find a specific value it's simple enough - you can store the data encrypted any way you like - even as a hash and still retrieve a specific value using an index. But as per my comment elsewhere, you can't do range queries without either:

- decrypting each and every row in the table

or

- using an algorithm that can be cracked in a few seconds.

Using a linked list (or a related table) to define order instead of an algorithm with intrinsic ordering would force a brute force check on a much larger set of values - but it's nowhere near as secure as a properly encrypted value.

It doesn't matter if you use Oracle, Java or pencil and paper. Might be possible using quantum computing - but if you can't afford to ensure the security of your application / pay for good advice from an expert cryptographer, then you certainly won't be able to afford that.

Comment: "decrypting each and every row in the table": As I am not going to do this inside the application, perhaps a function-based index on unencrypted values will do the job as the other answer has suggested. I left this question in my comment to that answer: would a function-based index reveal the values to the users including the DBA?

Comment: How do you create such a function without making the key accessible to the DBAs?

Answer (score 0):

How can I create an index on decrypted column values and somehow force Oracle to utilize this index? 
Maybe you could create a function based index in which you index the decrypted value.

```
create index ix1 on tablename (decryptfunction(pk1));
```

Comment: But that would store the unencrypted values in the index.

Comment: @symcbean That's true. But it's one or the other. You can't do a index range scan on an encrypted column if the index can't store the decrypted value. But is the index data accessible by normal users?

Comment: If i create a function-based index on decrypted values, would the index content be accessible by the DBA?

Comment: @Reza I'm not sure, but would like to know, I posted a question on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469060/can-a-user-dba-read-index-data-directly

Comment: Please look at the comment symcbean has left on the other answer. The function itself would be exposed to the DBA; thus, the values!